# Не везде отображается иконка приложения android

Tags: java, android, icon

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: не везде отображается иконка приложения. При установке отображается, в меню отображается, на рабочем столе отображается, а в настройках стандартная иконка android.
В манифеста у `application` указан атрибут `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"`, иконка лежит во всех требуемых разрешениях, названия иконок одинаковые.
Понял, что mipmap работает только с android 4.2+. Чтобы иконка отображалась на устройствах с ранней версией, нужно иконку поместить в папку drawable? Или есть другой вариант?

Comment: В последнее время студия по дефолту размещает иконку приложения в папках `mipmap-*/` - возможно с этим как то связано. Или перенесите туда свои или удалите папки `mipmap/`

Comment: у АПК файла нет иконки. APK - обычный zip-архив. У архивов нет иконок. Если иконка показывается в каком-либо файловом менеджере, это значит, что этот менеджер сам достает ее из архива. Это совершенно не стандартная фича

Comment: скриншоты и информация о девайсе/весии андроид могут помочь понять в чем проблема

Comment: при описании вопроса случайно неправильно указал путь (исправил уже), на самом деле лежат иконки в  папках `mipmap-*/`, атрибут `android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"` указан.  Названия иконок совпадают. Файловые менеджеры отказываются видеть иконку, в меню `настройки->приложения` иконка не отображается , при зажатии кнопки `home` также стандартная иконка вместо моей, а во всех других местах иконка отображается моя вместо стандартной. Боюсь, что скриншоты ничего Вам не скажут, т.к. такая ситуация на всех устройствах (Android 4+).

Answer (score 1):

Думаю, сделать надо **Build** - > **Clean Project** и потом **Build** - > **Rebuild Project**. Тогда, Androdi Studio заново соберет проект.

Comment: Спасибо, частично помогло. На Android 4.4+ стали отображаться иконки. На версиях ниже проблема по-прежнему осталась.